# How to move server environment to another server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, production-environment, vagrant

I have a VPS Linux Server with this environment: "rvm + ror + ngixn + passenger + unicorn + capistrano".

How to move server environment to another server fast?

I found:

1. http://gitpusshuten.com/
2. Vagrant http://vagrantup.com/

Who has experience with solving the problem?
Can you explain how to move (to copy) the server environment better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along the same line as those listed is Chef by OpsCode. It's based on ruby and relies on recipes to implement what you want, where you want.

http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home

Answer (score 0):

These all things will require file changes and server setting changes overall. So, it is not possible in one click. For each thing ("rvm + ror + ngixn + passenger + unicorn + capistrano") move there will be a seprate solution available. As for rails gem , you may use bundle install..etc. But I don't thing its possible in one click solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org). This will replicate everything exactly on the new server, so there maybe some problems if the hardware is different. I've used it to replace an OS on a partition in a multiboot system successfully.